# Angular - unable to filter recieved data according to a property using getter\setter

Tags: angular, typescript

In my app there's an array of objects with a boolean property that can change. Upon this property change, I emit `.next(changedData)` the changed array to the subscribed component.

In the component that is subscribed to data changes I need to filter that data accordingly and prepare it for `*ngFor`.

However, I cannot wrap my head around the proper usage of the setter\getter approach. I don't want to use `pipe`s since they can be inefficient in a large scale.

[I read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444484/1895488) but can't understand how it's done properly.

```js
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    
      private _listFilter: Data[];
        get listFilter(): Data[] {
          return this._listFilter;
        }
        set listFilter(filter: Data[]) {
          this._listFilter = filter;
          this.filteredData = this.performFilter(this.listFilter); //*ngFor is set on filteredData 
        }
       .
       .
       .
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataSub = this.dataService.DataList$.subscribe(result => {
          this.data = result;
          this.filteredData = this.data; //*ngFor is set on filteredData 
        });
      }
       .
       .
       .
      private performFilter(dataArr): Data[] {
      //isNewData  is the propery that has changed and I want to iterate only over a list of data which the boolean isNewData equals to true
        return dataArr.filter((data: Data) => data.isNewData === true ); 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just try to refactor it to `return dataArr.filter((data: Data) => data.isNewData);`